# What is wrong with this PHP MySQL Query?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I keep getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

For the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT `Gift`, `Type` 
            FROM `gifts` 
           WHERE `User`= '".mysql_real_escape_string($myuid)."' 
           LIMIT ".$start.", ".$end;
```

**Here is the code I use to GET the $start and $end Variables:**

```
$start = $_GET['start'];
if($start = "") {
  $start = 0;
}
$end = $_GET['end'];
if($end = "") {
  $end = 7;
}
```

**I Found The Problem:**

I tested this script in another browser, and it worked just fine. The problem is something with Internet Explorer 9. Anyone know why?

Comment: Are `$start` and `$end` guaranteed to be integers?

Comment: What are the values of $myuid, $start, and $end? Without those we have no way of determining whether your query is valid.

Comment: Prior to executing the query, echo it out and post that.

Comment: $myuid is an integer :1445788985   $start is alos an integer:  0  and so is $end:   7  Yes, they are always guarenteed to be an integer.

Comment: The [$_GET documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) shows using **double** quotes, not single.  Doesn't look like an IE9 issue to me

Comment: why are you using if($start="") instead of if(empty($start)) .Or if want to assign 0 to $start, use $start=0. Same thing for $end

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I ave treid replacing the quotes with double. I think it is IE( because this same code works in IE8, Opera, Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should print the query out before it's sent to the database:

```
$start = $_GET["start"];
$end = $_GET["end"];

$query = "SELECT `Gift`, `Type` 
            FROM `gifts` 
           WHERE `User`= '".mysql_real_escape_string($myuid)."' 
           LIMIT ".$start.", ".$end;

echo $query;
```

### Update

The OP provides in the comments to this answer that the start & end values aren't appearing in the output, and the values are supplied by a GET request.

The output would give us a better idea what the issue is, but I recommend using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to parameterize the query:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT g.gift,
                         g.type
                    FROM GIFTS g
                   WHERE g.user = '%s'
                   LIMIT %u, %u",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($myuid),
                  $_GET["start"], 
                  $_GET["end"]);
```

Comment: SELECT Gift, Type FROM gifts WHERE User='1794056140' LIMIT ,

Comment: @Zachary Brown: Then your $start & $end variables are not populated.  The `LIMIT` syntax expects at least one number, and two numbers if the comma is present to separate the two.

Comment: I'm not sure why. This is the URL:   http://zbrowntechnology.info/date/mygifts.php?start=0&end=7

Comment: Your URL does not automatically create variables by the same name. You read them out of `$_GET`.

Comment: @Zachary Brown: That's a URL, you need to populate the variables with the values from the GET request.

Comment: @OMG Ponies... I have doen this. I'll append the code to my post above.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of `mysql_real_escape_string($myuid)`. Maybe it is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

the error supplied should give you a clue -

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

It is saying that there is an error near ''. I would be checking then value of mysql_real_escape_string($myuid). ensure you have escaped any quotes "'" and that the value is already not quoted.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same trouble few minutes ago and that trouble was only on Internet explorer too. On Chrome, Firefox work just fine.

I know the script works fine as the Info is updated in the Database.

The trouble in my side was the **redirection** after the process.
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=fileX.php" />`
And as I can see IE does not like to have url in lower case.
By setting it this way`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;**URL**=fileX.php" />`it works just fine.

First time it runs ok. But then it refresh and has 0 valu so that why we are getting that error from SQL. At my eye this is not a server side error but IE that does not want to read the code as all other browser.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to answer something else.

Answer (score -7):

Some of your quotes are all at an angle; they need to be like this: ' not: `

Comment: No, in mysql this is correct (althogh they are completely optional if there are no special characters or reserved names involved). Though I am not sure about the table name...

Comment: @yankee: MySQL uses backticks to escape special characters & reserved words in both columns and table names.